# How do russian tanks compare to german tanks?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

In almost every conflict I have been in the russian T-34 tank (medium) is defeated when engaging a german panzer (medium).

Are there any tank stats available to show the dmg/armor per tank.  Or at least the outcome of 1v1 fights between tanks?

I am new and it seems to me the german tanks are far superior.

Comment: Side note: As "panzer" means "tank", "panzer tank" is rather redundant. ;)

Comment: You will need multiple tanks per one german tank. That was how it was in the real war aswell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is historically accurate. German tanks were 1 for 1 better than just about anything else in the world. They were unfortunately very precisely engineered and thus prone to breakdown in adverse conditions such as Russia, so the cheaper and more tolerant Russian tanks were able to survive on sheer numbers and being fairly easy to fix compared to their German counterparts who were on longer supply lines to start with. I assume you mean The T-34 since the [T-35](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-35) was a very obscure prewar tank that was definitively inferior to almost everything.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-34):

> The T-34 was developed from the BT series of cavalry tanks in 1940, and was intended to replace both the BT-5 and BT-7 tanks and the T-26 infantry tank then in service.[9] At its introduction, it was the tank with the best balance of firepower, mobility, protection and ruggedness, although its battlefield effectiveness suffered from the unsatisfactory ergonomic layout of its crew compartment, scarcity of radios, and poor tactical employment. The two-man turret crew arrangement required the commander to aim and fire the gun, an arrangement common to many tanks of 1940; this proved to be inferior to the three-man (commander, gunner, and loader) turret crews of German Panzer III and Panzer IV tanks. However, according to analysis at the Aberdeen Proving Grounds of a T-34 sent over by the Soviets in 1942, the T-34 had the best optics of any tank so far analyzed there.[10] In early 1944, the improved T-34-85 was introduced, with a more powerful 85 mm (3.35 in) gun and a substantially improved three-man turret design with heavier armour.

The Germans ultimately lost, among many other reasons, due to the massive overproduction of T-34s more than the overall power of that tank.

As far as the game goes, since it's still in beta, things may change some for balance reasons but it is unlikely that the balance will change all that much. Expect to see hard stats and analysis to appear when the game properly releases.